# Is it possible to add Swift 4.1 to Xcode 10

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode10, swift4.2, swift4.1

My app is currently working on Swift 4.1 in Xcode 9.4.1.
Apple announced they will only allow apps built from Xcode 10 as of March 2019. Xcode 10 now only supports Swift 3.3, 4.0 and 4.2.
My app can only be run on Swift 4.1 (because of reasons).

Is it possible to make Xcode 10 run Swift 4.1?

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use Swift 4.1 , you can try to build your own Swift 4.1 from the source code using [the GitHub project](https://github.com/apple/swift). I'm not sure that this is a nice solution. It's too complicated, in my opinion. No way to use 4.1.
By the way, you can try to use old xcodebuild system from Swift9.4.1 for your code.

Answer (score 0):

i had my project in swift 4.1 and then i downloaded xcode 10 and select swift language version swift 4 it must work as its working in my project. but swift 4.1 is not available in xcode 10.